# Is there a way to undo edits done inside a specific region intelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, undo, undo-redo

I am using intellij for development purpose. I wonder whether it has a feature where I can select a region (say I highlighted a method block), and undo edits done in that region. i.e. I am going upwards through the history local to that region.

Anyone knows whether there's any feature similar to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually select all the text of that region, then right click (context menu) and select Local History -> Show History for Selection

It is not as fine grained as Ctrl-Z, though. You only get snapshots at specific events (updating from VCS, running a run/debug configuration, saving the file (I am not sure about that one), ...).

Comment: Thank for the answer, is it bound to the line number? or smart enough to identify the location. ex; assume a method implementation block?

Comment: It is bound to the line num as I tried out. Anyway thnx :))

Comment: When I tried it, IDEA intelligently identified the block, even if I had inserted lines at the top of the file. Maybe it depends on whether IDEA is given enough context in the selection to identify the block in the different revisions.